# UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput - Program continues without waiting for text input from user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm sort of stuck on a UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput.  (My code is too long to post here, but this is the part where the problem exists.)  It all sort of works, but the program doesn't wait until the user enters the information before continuing.  The "editName" button doesn't change the display in the code below, but the updateDisplay button works fine (if you've pressed the "editName" button before you pressed "updateDisplay").  How can I get everything to sort of halt until the user enters the info (or cancels).  Or is there some other lead that will take me where I need to go. (I've been toying with putting the rest of the code in the -(void) alertView, but that just doesn't seem to be the correct way of doing it).

Thanks in advance.

```
#import "HSTestViewController.h"

@implementation HSTestViewController
@synthesize display;

NSString *newName;

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

{    
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
        newName = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    }
}


- (void) getNewName;
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You made the High Score List"
                                                message:@"Please enter your name"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];

    alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    [alert show];
}

- (IBAction)editName:(id)sender 
{
    [self getNewName];    
    newName = display.text;
}

- (IBAction)updateDisplay:(id)sender 
{
    display.text = newName;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add UIAlertViewDelegate to the class. And implement the below delegate method.

OK button index value will be 1 in your case.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex) 
    {
        // call the method or the stuff which you need to perform on click of "OK" button.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I moved some things like you suggested and now my program now does exactly what I intended it to do.  I also added the UIAlertViewDelegate, which I had not done before.